# Click outside MUI Modal Component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to use Modal Component in MUI with chat bot. If modal is open, user will interact with buttons, inputs outside modal. How to do it?

I expect to click outside modal and do not close modal

```
Modal
  open={open}
  onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
  BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
  BackdropProps={{
    onClick: handleOutsideClick,
  }}
>
  {/* Modal content */}
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `onClose` prop in `Modal`, because it is the prop that handles the closing behavior when clicking outside the modal. If you don't pass this prop, the modal will not close on click outside, but only when you call the `setOpen` function explicitly.

For example:

```
<Modal open={open}>
  <Button onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
</Modal>
```

However, by default, the `Modal` component in MUI is designed to prevent interaction with the content outside the modal. This is to avoid conflicting behaviors and ensure that the user focuses on the modal task. If you want to enable interaction with the components outside the modal, you can use alternatives such as `Popper`.

`Popper` is a component that displays some content on top of another, but it does not block interaction with the rest of the page. It also has some advantages over `Modal`, such as positioning and anchoring.

For example:

```
<Popper open={open} anchorEl={popperRef.current} placement="bottom-start">
  <Box sx={style}>
    <Button onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
  </Box>
</Popper>
```

You can see the whole example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-breeze-jldp7y?file=/Demo.tsx).